# showing username after login on the website

Tags: php, html, session

I am designing a website with login page. the login part and fetching from db works fine. but i want to show the username on the homepage after logging in. i use session_start(). but the username is not showing. i checked similar questions here but none of them was the answer for me. followings are codes:
php code:

```
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
$sel_user = "select * from admins where email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
if($check_user>0)
{
$_SESSION['email']=$email
echo "<script>window.open('index2.html','_self')</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";
}
```

index2.html :

```
<?php
       session_start();
?>
    <div class="inline-block">
                                <h5 class="no-margin"> Welcome </h5>
                                <h4 class="no-margin"> <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?> </h4>
                                <a class="btn user-options sb_toggle">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

Comment: You have to `start_session()` in every file of your php script including where are you setting the `$_SESSION['email']`

Comment: You using php tags on html file. change index_2.html to index_2.php...done

Comment: You have to place a semi-colon at the end of $_SESSION['email']=$email found in the first file.

Comment: @noor that was what you said! problem solved ! thanks

Comment: @user3696174 Welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

**First code**:

```
session_start();
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
$sel_user = "select * from admins where email='$email' AND password='$pass'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
if($check_user>0)
{
    $_SESSION['email']=$email
    echo "<script>window.open('index2.html','_self')</script>";
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";
}
```

**index2.php** :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<div class="inline-block">
    <h5 class="no-margin"> Welcome </h5>
    <h4 class="no-margin"> <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?> </h4>
    <a class="btn user-options sb_toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

It should work.

Comment: I already added AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm into my htaccess. so I can run php in my html.but as your code is mentioning i should ve added a session start also in my php code. so it is working now. thnks

Comment: Welcome, Glad to help you!

Comment: *"There is a big mistake that is you can't run PHP in .html file."* - That's false and should be discarded from the answer, or modified to read something like: *"You need to instruct Apache to treat .html files as PHP"*, just like the OP said they used.